# Google Sheets APIの利用料金について

Tags: google-api, google-spreadsheet

お世話になっております。
私の制作しているアプリでGoogle Cloud Platformの「google-sheets-api」を使用しています。
リクエストの上限として1ユーザーにつき、100秒間に100回までが無料枠の上限として設けられており、請求アカウントと連携することで上限の割当てを増やすことができますが、具体的な料金体系がSheets APIのドキュメントに記載がされておりません。
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits
つきましては、利用料金についてご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんちには、はじめまして。

Google Docs APIと同様に無料とのことです。G Suiteに関するAPIは明記のないCalendarも含め現状では無料で利用できます。

クォーターを超えて利用する場合は、請求アカウントを紐づけしてください。本人確認やリソースの濫用を防ぐ意図かと思われます。

将来的にどうなるかや、公式な回答が必要な場合は、Googleの担当窓口までお尋ねいただくのがよいと思います。

関連URL
https://developers.google.com/docs/api/pricing
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6103110?hl=ja
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620439/does-google-charges-for-api-requests-made-to-google-sheet-docs-calendar-etc

Comment: 早速ご回答いただきありがとうございます。請求アカウントの意図含め、納得いたしました。Google Cloud Platformの担当窓口へは以前問合せしていたのですが、扱っていないとの回答を受け、こちらに質問させていただいた次第です。正しくはG Suite管理者の問合せフォームへの問合せでしたのですね。大変助かりました。ありがとうございます。